# C#, How to Consistantly bring a form to the front?

Tags: c#

I have a `MainForm` Class Instance, 
I bring up another form like so;

```
InputForm MyInput= new InputForm("Enter a Number");
MyInput.ShowDialog();
```

I close `MyInput` form from within itself like this;

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do things here
        this.Hide();

    }
```

Flow resumes in the MainForm and using either

```
this.Show();
```

or

```
this.Activate();
```

neither will consistantly bring the `MainForm` to the front.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is show your InputForm like this. This form of [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe.aspx) assigns the owner to your dialogbox.

```
DialogResult dr = MyInput.ShowDialog(this);
//test for result here

MyInput.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.Hide()` appears to be hiding the main form, not the input.  Because `ShowDialog` is a blocking method, the InputForm will need to be closed by user action, code internal to the InputForm, or by another thread.

Comment: Ok, So how should I close the MyInput Form?
It closes upon a buttonclick at the moment

Comment: Actually, msdn [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) `When a form is displayed as a modal dialog box, clicking the Close button (the button with an X at the upper-right corner of the form) causes the form to be hidden and the DialogResult property to be set to DialogResult.Cancel.`, so I think you shouldn't `Close()` it

Comment: I am Hiding it `@ Fawques`
Code Updated.
Should I just change the Visibility?